# Make Web API 2 self host support auto generated `API description` page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I originally created the ASP.NET Web API 2 with VS2013 wizard which is default with IIS express hosted, and it have a default controller named `HomeController`:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";

        return View();
    }
}
```

which acts by below **url** and UI:

[image]

click the **API** link, which provide a summarized report for describe all the API controller interfaces, then the user developer know how to call these APIs:

[image: API report]

Later, I was trying to switch this project to **self host**, I basically did nothing but change the project type to **Console** and add the `Program.cs`, finally added a new `SelfHostStartup.cs`:

```
public class SelfHostStartup
{
    // This code configures Web API. The Startup class is specified as a type
    // parameter in the WebApp.Start method.
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        // Configure Web API for self-host. 
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        // Web API configuration and services
        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));
        ConfigureAuth(appBuilder);

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        // !possible! the HOME page route settings.
        RouteTable.Routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
    }
```

after running the Console program, all the API controller is working fine by tested in Browser, but test again with these urls

- `http://localhost:9000/home/index`
   show a blankpage
- `http://localhost:9000/api/home/index`

> No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:9000/api/home/index'.
>   
>   
>   No type was found that matches the controller named 'home'.

- `http://localhost:9000/home/`
   show a blankpage

I guess this related to the html and js file loading, seems the self host mode didn't load those files?

anyone could help?

Comment: `http://localhost:9000/home/index` doesn't exist in your set up. You should be testing against `http://localhost:9000/api/home/index`

Comment: The page you show in your screenshot is `http://localhost:9000/help/index` not `home/index`...

Answer (score 0):

I did some work to achieve similar function by adding another controller, and adding one function to it to list all existed API:

```
public class CloudApiParameter
{
    public string ParameterName { get; set; }
    public string ParameterType { get; set; }
}

public class CloudApiDescription
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string RelativePath { get; set; }
    public string Document { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<CloudApiParameter> Parameters { get; set; }

}

public IEnumerable<CloudApiDescription> Get()
{
    var apiDescs = Configuration.Services.GetApiExplorer().ApiDescriptions;
    return apiDescs.Select(r => new CloudApiDescription()
    {
        Id = r.GetFriendlyId(),
        RelativePath = r.RelativePath,
        Document = r.Documentation,
        Parameters = (r.ParameterDescriptions.Any() ? r.ParameterDescriptions.Select(p => new CloudApiParameter()
        {
            ParameterName = p.ParameterDescriptor.ParameterName,
            ParameterType = p.ParameterDescriptor.ParameterType.ToString()
        }): null)
    });
}
```

Comment: finally, there's a link to achieve this:    http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/creating-api-help-pages